# Get uitextfield data from custom uitableview cell - Swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, uitextfield

I have a problem with custom tableview cell with a textfield. So, I have a separate class for a cell with a textfield, but I can't retrieve data in my tableview class. There is a delegate for textfield in tableview class and textFieldShouldReturn function but nothing happens when I press "Done" button. Where can be a problem?

Thanks a lot!

Here's a code for Table View:

```
class MainTVC: UITableViewController, UITextFieldDelegate{

    var tableParts: [Dictionary<String, Any>] = []

    override func viewWillAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(true)
        tableParts = [
            ["type": "title", "data": "Some data", "enabled": true],
            ["type": "date", "data": "Some data", "enabled": true],
            ["type": "location", "data": "Loading...", "enabled": true],
        ]
        tableView.reloadData()
    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        tableView.delegate = self
        tableView.dataSource = self
    }

    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int { return 1 }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int { return tableParts.count }

    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        var cell = tableParts[indexPath.row]
        switch(cell["type"] as! String) {
        ...
        case "textbox":
            let rTemplateTextBox = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recapTextCell", for: indexPath) as! RTextCell
            rTemplateTextBox.textField.text = cell["data"] as? String ?? "No text"

            rTemplateTextBox.data = cell
            return rTemplateTextBox
        default:
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "defCell", for: indexPath)
            cell.textLabel?.text = "Unknown type of cell!"
            return cell
        }

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("Should return!")
        return true
    }
}
```

And for a cell:

```
class RTextCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var textField = UITextField()
    var data: Dictionary<String, Any>?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textField.delegate = self

        let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 15, height: self.frame.height))

        textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: 40))
        textField.placeholder = "Your text here"
        textField.textColor = UIColor.white
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.white
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.leftView = padding
        textField.leftViewMode = .always

        self.addSubview(textField)
    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("Should return")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        if data != nil {
            data!["data"] = textField.text
            print("DATA: \(data!)")
        } else {
            print("No data")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please include relevant code for both your `UITableViewCell` subclass and your tableview controller class.

Comment: @Cheslav i think my answer solve your problem

Comment: you are setting textfield.delegate in RTextCell class. So the textFieldShouldReturn will work only in that class. Where will you use data of textfield. pls explain?

Comment: @AadilAli I want to use field's text in my tableview class, there is a dictionary and I want to populate it with data from each textfield. There will be many textfields in each cell.

Comment: "Done" button is part of your cell?

Comment: @AadilAli nope, "Done" button is a part of a keyboard.

Comment: add this line rTemplateTextBox.textField.delegate = self in cellForRow under case "textbox" and remove textfield.delegate from RTextCell . Textfield delegate methods should work in MainTvc. you can get data from textfield.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First issue -- in your cell class, in `awakeFromNib()` you have:

```
// CREATE a UITextField
var textField = UITextField()
var data: Dictionary<String, Any>?

override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()

    // assign self as the delegate of textField
    textField.delegate = self

    let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 15, height: self.frame.height))

    // CREATE a NEW UITextField
    textField = UITextField(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: 40))
```

So, when you create the NEW textField, it no longer has a delegate assigned to it. That's why nothing triggers `textFieldShouldReturn` or `textFieldDidEndEditing`.

Replace the `UITextField(frame: ..)` line with:

```
    textField.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: 40)
```

Next, instead of passing in a "data object" to then try and manipulate, think about using a call-back closure.

Change your cell class to this:

```
class RTextCell: UITableViewCell, UITextFieldDelegate {

    var textField = UITextField()

    // this will be our "call back" closure
    var didEndEditAction : ((String)->())?

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        textField.delegate = self

        let padding = UIView(frame: CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: 15, height: self.frame.height))

        // just set the frame, don't create a NEW textField
        textField.frame = CGRect(x:0, y:0, width: self.frame.width, height: 40)
        textField.placeholder = "Your text here"
        textField.textColor = UIColor.white
        textField.tintColor = UIColor.white
        textField.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        textField.leftView = padding
        textField.leftViewMode = .always

        self.addSubview(textField)

    }

    func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        print("Should return")
        return true
    }

    func textFieldDidEndEditing(_ textField: UITextField) {
        // call back using a closure
        didEndEditAction?(textField.text ?? "")
    }

}
```

And then configure it like this:

```
    case "textbox":
        let rTemplateTextBox = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "recapTextCell", for: indexPath) as! RTextCell
        rTemplateTextBox.textField.text = cell["data"] as? String ?? "No text"

        // setup the "call back" closure
        rTemplateTextBox.didEndEditAction = {
            (newText) in
            let cell = self.myData[indexPath.row]
            cell["data"] = newText
        }

        return rTemplateTextBox
```

Answer (score 0):

You can get cell `textField` data anywhere where your `tableView` is declared just use the following code

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: yourRow, section: yourSection)
let cell:InputDataCell = yourTable.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! InputDataCell

if (cell.yourTextFieald.text?.characters.count)! {
    print(cell.yourTextFieald.text!)                           
}
```