# How to create outlet from collection cell xib file to collection view controller

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, xib

I have custom `Collection View Cell` and .swift and .xib file for it. In the .xib file I have `textField` which I have to take the data from in `Collection ViewController` and act accordingly but I am not sure how because the .xib file has the custom class of the `Collection View Cell` and I **cannot create** outlet to the `Collection ViewController` file so I can refer to it.

And if I create an outlet in `Collection View Cell` I can't refer to it in `Collection ViewController`.

Comment: There are plenty of example for getting the data entered in a text field in a table view cell - the process for a collection view cell will be almost identical. Here is one example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45410881/get-uitextfield-data-from-custom-uitableview-cell-swift

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do that.
You can't create an outlet that references a UITextField placed inside a custom CollectionViewCell in your CollectionViewController.

What you can do is create an outlet that references the UITextField in your .xib in the respective CollectionViewCell .swift class ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qIg05.jpg)), create an outlet that references your collectionView in the CollectionViewController ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEcbN.jpg)), and use these CollectionViewCells in your collectionView ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6Gg.jpg)).

You can then access the UITextField of a specific CollectionViewCell in your CollectionViewController through the cell itself ([3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6Gg.jpg)), like for instance with:

```
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: 2, section: 0)
let cell = self.collectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell // so the compiler knows that the cell you are referring to is of type CollectionViewCell and thus has your custom textField property

let textInTextField = cell.textField.text
```

---

(1)

[image]

(2)

[image]

(3)

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much I fixed the problem. Do you know why when keyboard is showed from textField the cell moves up leaving white space...

Comment: @Viktor . Don't know exactly, how are you managing the views when the keyboard appears?

Comment: Nothing special I just have textField.resignFirstResponder() in textFieldShouldReturn() . Here is the cell correct layout before I open keyboard - https://i.stack.imgur.com/AgCyX.png and here is after I show keyboard - https://i.stack.imgur.com/Nnl43.png

Comment: If you are using a UICollectionViewController, maybe it embeds the logic to move the views when the keyboard appears. In that case you may try to use a normal UIViewController with delegates and data source as in https://i.stack.imgur.com/IEcbN.jpg and https://i.stack.imgur.com/aS6Gg.jpg to see if the behavior changes. But I don't know for sure.

Comment: When this shows up if I go onto the next cell I have the cell once again moved up so this happens to all the cells...

Answer (score -1):

As far as I could understand, you need a way to access the CollectionViewController data from your CollectionViewCell, if this is the case you can try the following:

```
extension UIView {
    var parentViewController: UIViewController? {
        var parentResponder: UIResponder? = self
        while parentResponder != nil {
            parentResponder = parentResponder!.next
            if let viewController = parentResponder as? UIViewController {
                return viewController
            }
        }
        return nil
    }
}

//In the CollectionViewCell class
if let controller = self.parentViewController as? YourViewController
{
    controller.action()
}
```

Through this extension you can access the parent controller of your cell and execute functions or obtain data as needed

An example: 
https://github.com/AngelH2/CollectionViewCell-Comunication/tree/master/CollectionCellAction

Comment: Thanks for the help, I tried adding the extension and added this code in my cell but the compiler doesn't go at all into the if statement and I can run the simulator...:                                                                                    if let controller = self.parentViewController as? CollectionOneController {
            print(controller.simpleAction())
        }

Comment: Does that function return any value to print ?. In my case, I have that function added for an image viewer in which I have 2 buttons to move to the left and right in my CollectionViewCell, since I needed some way to execute a function in the parent controller from the cell to be able to do a scroll, I used that function and it turned out very well

Comment: If the code does not work, try the following: add a button in the cell and program it so that when you press it, call the main controller function

Comment: how do I make so when pressed it can call the main controller function ? Can you update the question with some code ?